# How to Pass Parameters to Middleware in Slim 2?

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to figure out how to pass parameters to a middleware in slim 2. I have a specific use case where I need to customize the behavior of a middleware based on certain parameters.

Here's an example of the middleware code:

```
$app->post('/test',function () use ($app) { })->setMiddleware([new TestMiddleware(), 'call']);
```

I cannot add parameters in the object as no constructor can be used in the middleware.
I tried to add the parameters in the request inside the router but the middleware is called first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation of slime v2
[Middleware for routes](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v2/routing/middleware.html)

You'll find some helpful examples, like this one:

```
<?php
$authenticateForRole = function ( $role = 'member' ) { -> defining an anonymous function
    return function () use ( $role ) { -> returns a callback
        ...code...
    };
};


                             | Uses here the custom middleware with the given param 
                             v
$app->get('/foo', $authenticateForRole('admin'), function () {
    //Display admin control panel
});
```

Now, for the piece of code you've provided, it makes use of the class `TestMiddleware` and the function `call`

```
$app->post('/test',function () use ($app) { })->setMiddleware([new TestMiddleware(), 'call']);
```

So if we take the example provided above as guidance your code should look like this:

**TestMiddleware.php**

```
<?php
class TestMiddleware {
    public static function call($msg) {
        return function () use($msg) {
        ...code...
            echo $msg;
            echo "<br>";
        ...code...
        };
    }
}
```

**Index.php**

```
$app->get('/test',TestMiddleware::call("Middleware Message"), function () {
    echo "Route Message";
});
```

This will be displayed in the browser

```
Middlewared Message
Route Message
```

Last, if you want to use your `call` function like this:

```
TestMiddleware::call("Middleware Message")
```

you'll need to use the `static` keyword, otherwise you've to instantiate the class and pass it to the route:

```
$middlware = new TestMiddleware();

$app->get('/test',$middlware->call("Middleware Message"), function () {
    echo "Route Message";
});
```

**Edit:**

Okay, I spent some time modifying the code to meet the requirements and I've found multiple solutions to do it, however the most optimal and best in my opinion is this one:

```
// CustomMiddleware.php
class CustomMiddleware extends \Slim\Middleware{

    private $state;
    private $msg;

    // Constructor function
    public function __construct($msg,$state) {
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->msg = $msg;
    }

    // Invoke function
    public function __invoke()
    {
        $this->app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        $this->call();
    }

    // Call function
    public function call() {
        // if the variable state is false it returns an error 404 
        if(!$this->state) $this->app->halt(404,"Not Found");

        // else returns a message defined by the variable $this->msg
        else{
            $this->app->response()->write($this->msg);
            echo "<br>";
        }

        if ($this->next) $this->next->call();
    }
}

// Setting the parameters of the middleware
$middCallback = function () {
    $msg = "Middleware Message";
    $state = true;

    $middleware = new CustomMiddleware($msg,$state);
    $middleware(); // calling the __invoke
};

// Defining the route and including the middleware + callback
$app->get('/test', $middCallback , function () { 
    echo "Route Message";
});
```

I'll give you a brief explanation.

Here, `CustomMiddleware` inherits properties and methods from the class Middleware

```
class CustomMiddleware extends \Slim\Middleware{
```

The constructor is used to retrieve parameters `$state` and `$msg`.

```
    private $state;
    private $msg;

    // Constructor function
    public function __construct($msg,$state) {
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->msg = $msg;
    }
```

You may ask why we're not getting the parameters through the `call()` function?  Well, If you take a look at the source code you will find out that `call()` is an abstract function that doesn't accept parameters because it belongs to the `Middleware` class, meaning `CustomMiddleware` is just implementing it

I had trouble setting the middleware parameters, so I had to use an invoke function.

This is how normaly you will set a middleware in Slim:

1st option

```
  $app->add(middleware) // It works, however it is set globally (for all routes).
```

2nd option

```
$app->get('/test',function () { 
    echo "Route Message";
})->add(middleware); // It doesn't work (I guess it's because of the v2 of Slim).
```

3rd

```
$app->get('/test',function () { 
    echo "Route Message";
})->setMiddleware(middleware); // It works, however I can't set the parameters.
```

Now, the way I did it is by invoking the instance of the object `CustomMiddleware` as a function using `$middleware()`, which activates the invoke method. Within the invoke method you can trigger the execution of another function, in this case the `call` function, avoiding like this calling it manually

What I wanted to avoid:

```
$middleware = new CustomMiddleware($msg,$state);
$middleware->call();
```

What I expected:

```
$middleware = new CustomMiddleware($msg,$state);
$middleware();
```

The Invoke function:

```
public function __invoke()
{
    $this->app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $this->call();
}
```

The `call` function will be modified at your convenience, so there's not much to say.

```
public function call() {
    // if the state is false $this->state it will return an error 404
    if(!$this->state) $this->app->halt(404,"Not Found");

    // else will return the message $this->msg
    else{
        $this->app->response()->write($this->msg);
        echo "<br>";
    }
    // Calls for the next Middleware or route if available
    if ($this->next) $this->next->call(); -> 
}
```

The parameters are set here, with `$msg` and `$state` being the two variables, we pass the parameters to the instance of the object CustomMiddleware and the `__construct` will take care of it, last we have `$middleware()`, that will trigger the `__invoke` and the `call` function.

```
$middCallback = function () {
    $msg = "Middleware Message";
    $state = true;

    $middleware = new CustomMiddleware($msg,$state);
    $middleware();
};
```

Again, you may ask why I'm using an anonymous function.

Well, let's say we set the route like this:

```
$msg = "Middleware Message";
$state = true;
$middleware = new CustomMiddleware($msg,$state);

$app->get('/test', $middCallback , function () { 
    echo "Route Message";
});
```

If we pass the instance of the object as a argument to the route
you will get an error in the browser:

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: All Route middleware
> must be callable

Meaning that the instance `$middleware` passed to the route shouldn't be an object but a function

Last, we define the route.

We specify as second argument, the middleware defined earlier

```
// Defining the route and including the middleware + callback
$app->get('/test', $middCallback , function () { 
    echo "Route Message";
});
```

Doing this, you should have a working Middleware

Hope it helps

Cheers

Comment: I tried that after I posted the question, I can pass the parameter but I cannot halt the operation and return the response as I would do with middleware. For example in the TestMiddleware example you have given I cannot return this:  Response::error($msg);

Comment: @abcy122 I modified the post, see if it answers your question now